# 2-hop 'authorization code' flow oauth2 authentication for centrailzed social login

Tags: facebook, authentication, oauth-2.0, facebook-login, google-signin

## Introduction

I have my own user account database and am building an oauth2 authorization server to centralize authentication logic across my companies' websites using `authorization code` grant type.

Let's say I have deployed my authorization server's login page at `https://auth.my.company.com`, and deployed a website at `https://my.website1.com`.  When a user click on the `login` button at `https://my.website1.com`, the typical oauth2 authroization code flow will be triggered as shown in the picture below.

[image: typical oauth2 authorization code grant type]

To explain the picture:

1. The user access to `https://my.website1.com` which renders a login button.
2. The user is navigated to the centralized login page with url `https://auth.my.company.com?client_id=mysite1&redirect_url=https://my.website1.com/oauth/callback`
3. The user enters username and password and submit the login form.
4. After the authrization server validates the user credential, it redirects the user back the the redirect_url `https://my.website1.com/oauth/callback?auth_code=abcd` passing a parameter `auth_code=abcd`
5. The website backend server communicates with the authorization server using the input auth_code to authenticate the user, the authorization server returns an access token.
6. The website responses to the user that the login process is success.

## The Problem

At `https://my.website1.com`, I would like that the user can also login with his/her Facebook account, which will be bound with the account in my user account database. I would like to centralized this process as well (i.e. so that my another site `https://my.website2.com` can reuse the same login process). So I am thinking of implementing a 2-hop oauth flow as in the following picture.

[image: 2-hop oauth]

1. The user access to `https://my.website1.com` which renders a login button.
2. The user is navigated to my centralized Facebook login endpoint `https://auth.my.company.com/facebook`
3. The authorization resolves its Facebook client id and redirect url and then redirect the user to Facebook login page.
4. The user logins through Facebook.
5. Facebook redirects the user back to my authorization server, passing the authroization code.
6. My authorization server uses the authroization code from Facebook to authenticate the user with Facebook APIs
7. My authorization server redirects the user back to `https://my.website1.com` passing its own generated authorization code.
8. The website backend server communicates with the authorization server using the input auth_code to authenticate the user, the authorization server returns an access token.
9. The website responses to the user that the login process is success.

## Question

I cannot find any reference to this kind of 2-hop oauth so I am afraid that I am doing it wrong. I would like to know if there are standard approch the handle the centralized social login like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a reference from IBM website that looks very similar to the flow in question. [Here](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SS9H2Y_7.7.0/com.ibm.dp.doc/socialloginsupport_in_oauth_flow.html)